# File is not uploading on server and gives 500 internal server error in php

Tags: php, file-upload

I am tryiong to uploading a file in server via php My code works fine on localhost but whene i upload it to server and run it gives 500 internal server error and i am new bee and could not find erroe so please help me here is my code

```
  <?php
   $path=$_REQUEST['path'];
   if(!(file_exists('$path')))
   {
       //create the folder
       mkdir($path,0777,true);
       //give permission to the folder
       //chmod('C:/Users/dhanu-sdu/Desktop/test', 0777);
    }
    if (file_exists($path. $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
    {
        echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
        unlink ( $path. $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    }
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],$path. $_FILES["file"]      ["name"]);
    ?>
```

please people help me where is the bug in my code?

Comment: Look in the error logs on your server, you should see what the problem is there.

Comment: I dont have permissions to see the error log of server i only have ftp access

Comment: this is for checking weather the given path exist in server or not @ habib ul haq

Comment: ti is for conceiting the file name and file path @ habib ul haq

Comment: check your location of file in server...

Comment: yess sorry for that silly question

Comment: I have checked file location in server and i am passing path=3/ as parameter